# How I can increase tab width in notepad++ (v6.5)?

Tags: notepad++, indentation

This is example of two 4-space indentations
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG9CK.png

But indentation from notepad++ narrower with same number of spaces
How I can change it?

Comment: Hm, solution was pretty simple: just pick monospace font and turn it on in global settings.

Comment: maybe you can create an answer for solution that worked and accept it

Answer (score 133):

In version 7.2.2, the Tab Settings are under:

```
Settings > Preferences > Language > Tab Settings
```

Comment: still the same in 7.5.9

Comment: still the same in 7.8.1

Answer (score 13):

Notepad++ newest version, as of 2/24:
Settings > Preferences > Language > Tab Settings. It's the blue, underlined value labeled "Tab Size:", just click it.

Comment: In 7.5.9, I can click it, and change it to `8` in the little pop-up window, but the change isn't saved.

Comment: @RonJon, Just did this is 7.6.4, changed the tab size to 10, and hit ENTER. This made the little window go away. Closed and reopened Notepad++, and made a new Python file. Saw the tabs go to 10 characters. In fact if you do this with a Python file open at the same time, you should see tabs get larger or smaller.

Answer (score 13):

Version 7.8.1, from the main menu "Settings"->"Preferences..." on the very far right near the  bottom of the "Preferences" dialog you'll see "Tab size:" and a clickable link that you can use to change the size.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For versions prior to v7, you can find the option under:

**`Preferences > Settings > Tab Settings`**

Comment: I don't have `Tab Settings` under `Settings` (Notepad++ v7.5.1 (32 bit))