# How I can increase tab width in notepad++ (v7.5)?

Tags: text, notepad++, editor

v7.5.9

I've read [How I can increase tab width in notepad++ (v6.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181724/how-i-can-increase-tab-width-in-notepad-v6-5) and found that page, but the change from `4` to `8` doesn't "stick".

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make the tab value change, press enter.

The value will not 'stick' if you click the `X` to close. (I also have v7.5.9)